# Select cells until they no longer meet a condition, then continue

Tags: vba, excel

What I am hoping to do is sort through a column of information I have and sort it into rows. I need the date and then all of the non-number cells concatenated next to it. And then the next date on the line below the first date, etc.

So my column that looks like this:

```
42250
A
E
C
D
B
42244
E
F
42243
A
B
F
```

Would become:

```
42250 AECDB
42244 EF
42243 ABF
```

I feel pretty comfortable with the copying, concatenating, and pasting. What I am struggling with is how I might do the selections.

I am thinking in terms of:

- Select cell 1 (perform the copy/pasting actions).
- Then, select the next cell and continue to select as long as the
  contents are not numbers. If the next cell is a number, so not select
  it and do not move on. (perform the copy/pasting actions).
- Move to the next cell, if it is a number (perform the copy/pasting
  actions).
- Then, select the next cell and continue to select as long as the
  contents are not numbers. If the next cell is a number, so not select
  it and do not move on. (perform the copy/pasting actions).
- Continue until a cell is blank.

Comment: I suggest you show the code you have tried so far ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
Sub DoMagic()
    Dim lin As Integer
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim text As String

    start = 0
    lin = 1
    'the loop will continue until first blank cell
    While Len(Cells(lin, 1).Value) > 0
        'check if the cell content is numeric
        If IsNumeric(Cells(lin, 1).Value) Then
            'if start was already set, save the previous text
            If start <> 0 Then Cells(start, 2).Value = text
            'store the row index in start and erase text
            start = lin
            text = ""
            lin = lin + 1   'go to the next line
        Else
            'if it's not numeric, keep concatenating and deleting the line
            text = text & Cells(lin, 1).Value
            Cells(lin, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            'we don't need lin++ here because Delete does that
        End If
    Wend
    'store the last concatenated text if any
    If start <> 0 Then Cells(start, 2).Value = text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim actCell As Range
Dim t As Integer
Dim conc As String
Set actCell = Range("A1") '---- this is the first cell you want

Do
    t = 0
    conc = ""
    Do
        conc = conc & actCell.Offset(t) 'concatenate each cell
        t = t + 1
    Loop Until IsNumeric(Offset(t))
    Range("C600000").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = conc ' --- change this to what ever you want for your output
    Set actCell = actCell.Offset(t)
Loop Until actCell = ""
```